# How do you recycle a css file from a different theme into your new theme?

Tags: theming, webforms

I really like the form.css from Corolla. I have built a new theme, but would like to reuse Corolla's form.css.

1. Downloaded form.css from Corolla theme
2. Saved it to sites/all/themes/my_theme/css

Now what? Do I need to add a reference to this css file in the main css file? New to site building / theming, so our of my element.

Thanks - keb

Answer (score 1):

As @cilefen pointed out you need to do a couple of things.

1. Put the `form.css` on `sites/all/themes/my_theme/css/`.
2. Update your `sites/all/themes/my_theme/my_theme.info` file to have `stylesheets[all][] = css/form.css`.
3. Clear the cache.

Oh and make sure that `my_theme` is set to **default** or **at least active** in the page that your are working.

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's .info file, add the following:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/form.css
```

Comment: Gave that a shot, but no change after clearing cache. When I inspect, I see that the css is coming from the original Omega theme and not my subtheme...

Comment: stylesheets[all][] = css/form.css
css[monkey_theme_style.css][name] = Monkey theme global style.
css[monkey_theme_style.css][description] = This file holds all the globally active custom CSS of Monkey theme.
css[monkey_theme_style.css][options][weight] = 12
settings[alpha_css][monkey_theme_style.css] = 'monkey_theme_style.css'

Comment: @keb805 Did you put the `form.css` in `monkey_theme` (if that's your theme name) specifically in `monkey_theme/css`? The path should be `monkey_theme/css/form.css`.

Comment: Yes, I did add the form.css to sites/all/themes/monkey_theme/css/form.ccs. Is there a syntax issue?